# 'post_status' doesn't publish post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I write Function to store post in the database of wordpress

In the array of $post variable 'post_status' =>'publish'.. But I don't know Why when running the function save post 'future' no 'publish' Where problem?

```
  function ghoolo_mango(){
  $oiobz1 = writeMsg(1, 'center', '', 1);
  $bndate = bn_parsidate::getInstance();
  $bndate = $bndate->persian_date($input,$datetime,$lang);
    $postdater =  parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
    $postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ta = parsidate('j / F / Y',$datetime='now',$lang='pre');
    $postdate_gmt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $titles='لیست قیمت امروز طلا'    .$postdater;
    $posts = array(

        'post_content'   => $oiobz1,
        'post_name'      => $titles,
        'post_title'     => $titles,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_author'    => '1',
        'ping_status'    => 'open',
        'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_date'  => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_category' => array(40),
        'tags_input'     => "قیمت,قیمت روز,قیمت امروز,قیمت روزانه,قیمت لحظه ای,قیمت آنلاین,قیمت ماهانه,قیمت هفتگی,قیمت طلا $ta,قیمت امروز طلا$ta,قیمت طلا در تاریخ$ta,قیمت روزانه طلا,قیمت طلا امروز $ta,قیمت لحظه ای طلا$ta,قیمت مثقال طلا$ta,قیمت امروز مثقال طلا$ta,قیمت امروز طلا 24 عیار$ta,قیمت طلای 24 عیار $ta,قیمت امروز طلا 18 عیار $ta,قیمت طلا 18 عیار $ta , قیمت امروز انس نقره $ta,قیمت انس پلاتین $ta,قیمت انس پالادیم $ta,قیمت نفت سبک نفت $ta",
    );


    $post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);
    add_post_meta( $post_id, ' wp_insert_post', 0, true );


}
```

Comment: I Found The problem, top code should delete 'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,

Comment: Please don't put the solution in a comment but in an answer below. You can then also mark the question as solved. Also please provide reference to the Wordpress documentation that underlines your solution if posting.